# es6 class find array object class from element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 classes parent/child. In the parent class I need a way to return/find the child class from the clicked on element.

I am getting: 'find(...).toggle is not a function'

Here in a minimal example:

```js
class card {
  constructor(parent, element) {

    this.parent = parent;
    this.element = element;
  }

  toggle(expand) {
    //Do stuff
  }
}

class cards {
  constructor() {
    this.element = $(".cards");
    this.cards = [];


    this.element.children(".card").each((obj, el) => {
      console.log(el);
      this.cards.push(new card(this, $(el)));
    });

    $(document).click((event) => {
      var clickedOn = $(event.target);
      var $thisClosest = clickedOn.closest(".card");

      find($thisClosest).toggle();
    });
  }

  find(element) {
    this.cards.forEach((obj, el) => {
      if ($(el) == element)
        return obj; // need to return the class card
    });
  };

}

var my_a = new cards();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cards">
  one asdf
  <div class="card">card 1 asdf</div>
  <div class="card">card 2 asdf</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The cause of the error is because `find()` doesn't return anything to call `toggle()` on. That being said - could you please edit your question to include a description of what you're trying to achieve. I ask as I'm sure there's a better (and more simple) approach.

Comment: i am just trying to find the card from the element, as i will need to do more stuff with the card class

Comment: In my opinion you shouldn't create classes as wrappers around jQuery functionality. Instead create a jQuery plugin. Or else, abandon jQuery.

Comment: @trincot can i ask what you mean by a jQuery plugin, as im very new with all this. I just used classed because i know alittle c++, an classes are a big thing in c++

Comment: It is something specific for jQuery. See [How to create a basic plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/). Essentially you define a function as `$.fn.myfunction` and then you can write `$("myselector").myfunction()`. It makes your code integrate very nicely with existing jQuery style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `this.cards.find` instead of `this.cards.forEach` as `Array.forEach` [does not return any value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value).

[`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will return first element from array that matches the condition.

```js
find(element) {
  return this.cards.find((card) => card.element.is(element)));
};
```

I also used [jQuery's .is()](https://api.jquery.com/is/) as a more robust way to compare elements.

Comment: is there away to check if this.find($thisClosest) returns the card class?

Comment: Yes, `Array.find` returns either matching element or undefined so by checking `cardInstance.find(element) !== undefined` you can make sure that matching element is found.